# my table name is "images" but spring boot complains that "users_images" doesn't exist

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring boot, I made "User" entity which has a field "images" referencing "Images" entity. But it complains there is no "users_images" table that is specified nowhere, and it throws exceptions. What am I doing wrong?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //All images list
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Image> images;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Image Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "images")
public class Image{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Error message:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'chatboard.users_images' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2223) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.get(PersistentBag.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at com.blogspot.noteoneverything.chatboard.controller.ChatBoardController.home(ChatBoardController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]...
```

Comment: change `private List<UserImage> images;` to `private List<Image> images;` and check

Comment: @dkb Thank you for pointing out but same error.

Comment: For reference have a look, similar example on github: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa, also properties file: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `@OneToMany` relationship like below to prevent 3rd table creation by specifying the `mappedBy` attribute because you don't need a third table as each row of image will contain one user.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="user")
private List<Image> images;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update these stuffs:

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user" )
```

And if you want to create or update automatically your tables by JPA hibernate you need to add the below property:

```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

You can get more information on this relationship in this link: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many